# Different font styles within an unordered list

Tags: list, fonts, unordered

i'm relatively new to CSS/HTML and i'm trying to change the font of two parts within an unordered list.

Here is my HTML list

```
<ul id="factlist">
    <li>Name: Roger George Moore</li>
    <li>Born: 14 October 1927</li>
    <li>Birth Place: Stockwell, London</li>
    <li>Famous For: Playing James Bond 1973-1985</li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS

```
#factlist li {
/*Factlist contentright on Homepage*/
list-style-image: url('../images/bullets.png');
color: #ffffff;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 1.9em;
```

}

I basically want the list to appear with the 'headings' in italics and then the answer in normal. So like this...

*Name*: Roger Moore

*Born*: 14...

and so on.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<em>` tag ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em))

```
<ul id="factlist">
  <li><em>Name:</em> Roger George Moore</li>
  <li><em>Born:</em> 14 October 1927</li>
  <li><em>Birth Place:</em> Stockwell, London</li>
  <li><em>Famous For:</em> Playing James Bond 1973-1985</li>
</ul>
```

Or if you prefer using CSS use a `<span>`

```
<ul id="factlist">
  <li><span class="emphasize">Name:</span> Roger George Moore</li>
  <li><span class="emphasize">Born:</span> 14 October 1927</li>
  <li><span class="emphasize">Birth Place:</span> Stockwell, London</li>
  <li><span class="emphasize">Famous For:</span> Playing James Bond 1973-1985</li>
</ul>

li.emphasize {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it using CSS `font-style`. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-style.asp). [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BxQsM/).

**HTML**

```
<ul id="factlist">
    <li><span>Name</span>: Roger George Moore</li>
    <li><span>Born</span>: 14 October 1927</li>
    <li><span>Birth Place</span>: Stockwell, London</li>
    <li><span>Famous For</span>: Playing James Bond 1973-1985</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#factlist li {
    /*Factlist contentright on Homepage*/
    list-style-image: url('../images/bullets.png');
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.9em;
}

#factlist li span {
    font-style:italic;
}
```

---

Or you can use `<em>`. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_phrase_elements.asp). [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NyuX4/).

```
<ul id="factlist">
  <li><em>Name:</em> Roger George Moore</li>
  <li><em>Born:</em> 14 October 1927</li>
  <li><em>Birth Place:</em> Stockwell, London</li>
  <li><em>Famous For:</em> Playing James Bond 1973-1985</li>
</ul>
```